# Annoying css overriding declarations made lower in the code?

Tags: html, css

It seems the cascading part of css doesn't apply in this situation. I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong. If you use a class/element selector combo (`.core-services li`) does that somehow give the it supremacy over future lines that try to overwrite it? (The media query declaration is being "overlooked"). The only thing that works is !important, which I want to avoid if possible.

html:

```
  <section class="core-services">
      <div class="site-wrap">
          <ul>
              <li class="green_1">
                  <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
                  <p>Efficiently unleash cross-media information                          without cross-media value.</p>
              </li>
              <li class="green_2">
                  <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
                  <p>Efficiently unleash cross-media information                          without cross-media value.</p>
              </li>
              <li class="green_3">
                  <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                  <p>Efficiently unleash cross-media information                          without cross-media value.</p>
              </li>
              <li class="green_4">
                  <i class="fa fa-terminal"></i>
                  <p>Efficiently unleash cross-media information                          without cross-media value.</p>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </section>
```

css:

```
.core-services {
    background-color: #00873B;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.core-services ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.core-services li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 45px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
    .green_4 {
        margin-top: 1.7%;
    }
}

.core-services i {
    font-size: 80px;
    color: rgb(57, 55, 57);
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/lugacazine/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: How does the output differ from what you expected?

Comment: I expect the code in the media query to run, but it's overridden

Comment: http://specificity.keegan.st use that to check specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity and that to learn more on the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.green_4 has a specificity of 0010 while .core-services li has a specificity of 0011. In order to up the specificity of .green_4, add its parent selector like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
    .core-services .green_4 {
        margin-top: 1.7%;
    }
```

}

Go here to read more about CSS specificity: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity